# Problema de conexión base de datos a archivo js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

les expongo mi problema. Estoy realizando una base de datos para mi página, y en este punto, necesito enlazarla a mi archivo js para guardar y modificar los elementos que voy añadiendo. Para realizar este trabajo utilizo nodejs con la librería mysql, visual studio code como entorno de desarrollo, y por parte de la base de datos, la he creado en 000webhost con phpmyadmin. Hasta acá todo bien, el inconveniente está en que al iniciar la conexión con nodemon app.js (que es el nombre de mi archivo js) concluye en el error que aparece en la siguiente foto error (foto1)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/amQkG.png

Aquí está el archivo app.js desde donde realizo la conexión

archivo app.js (foto2)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuAVp.png

y esta es la base de datos creada dentro de 000webhost
nombre y usuario de base de datos (foto3)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyCsj.png

base de datos simple con fin de ejemplificación (foto4)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zj2iY.png

la verdad es que soy principiante, pero he visto varios videos similares y se supone que debería introducir el nombre de la base de datos (que aparece en la 3era foto pero tachado), en el campo database en app.js, y el usuario que se encuentra en 000webhost en la casilla user de mi archivo, y por último la contraseña que le coloco en la sección manage, change my password. Aunque los vídeos que he visto del tema son directamente de phpmyadmin y no de una base de datos en 000webhost, supuse que sería lo mismo, pero no hay forma de que inicie la conexión, no se si es que me falta algún paso por tener mi base de datos en un host o que está mal. Muchas gracias por su atención.

Comment: En mi comentario no incluyo ni código, ni mensajes de error

Comment: Listo, ya corregí el link que estaba en otro formato